# Allow user to see job listing while applying

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I like being able to apply through Stack Overflow, but I find it annoying that I can't see the job description at the same time I am writing the cover letter. I'd prefer to be able to see both on the same screen so that I can tailor the letter to the content of the description.

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea. We're currently running some experiments on the Apply form and don't have a change like this planned, but agree that it may be a better user experience. Will keep this in mind as we plan future improvements.